# BeautifulSoup table data extraction - data not showing up

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

-2 to make this 30 characters is some top kek information based for things idfk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you yourself found out, the element is **not** present in the page source, and is loaded dynamically through an AJAX request. The `urllib` module (or `requests`) returns the page source, which is why you won't be able to get that value directly.

Go to `Developer Tools` > `Network` > `XHR` and refresh the page. You'll see an AJAX request made to [this url](https://ethplorer.io/service/service.php?data=0x8b353021189375591723e7384262f45709a3c3dc):

```
https://ethplorer.io/service/service.php?data=0x8b353021189375591723e7384262f45709a3c3dc
```

This url returns the data in the form of JSON. If you have a look at it, you can get the `Holders` number from it using `requests` module and the built-in `.json()` method.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://ethplorer.io/service/service.php?data=0x8b353021189375591723e7384262f45709a3c3dc')
data = r.json()

holders = data['pager']['holders']['total']
print(holders)
# 2346
```

Comment: The most amazing code, I've seen for crawling table like data. And that JSON is insane. upvote.