# Find Elements by their Attribute in Python Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I have to deal with a table like this :

```html
<table id="product">
  <tr>
    <td data-sortable-id="ax01">Axe</td>
    <td>Wood</td>
    <td>Red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-sortable-id="ha01">Hammer</td>
    <td>Iron</td>
    <td>Black</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-sortable-id="na01">Nail</td>
    <td>Metal</td>
    <td>Black</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">3 Products Listed</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I select all `td` elements which have the attribute `data-sortable-id`? I can't find anything in Google search about finding elements by attribute (without a value, attribute's own name only).

I've tried something like

```
x = webdriver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@data-sortable-id]")
print(len(x))
```

but the result is 0.

Comment: give us your initial code that you have tried so far

Comment: try to inspect xpath for td element.

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49426387/beautifulsoup-table-data-extraction/49426592#comment85854543_49426592, I think it can help you.

Comment: @the.salman.a i dont know what you want to show me? i cant get it.. can you please give me a little advice?

Comment: The link that I shared had similar problem, Follow that answer. may be you'll need to modify that code a bit. But, then again, the fun is in making our own codes. Isn't it!

Comment: @the.salman.a, i need only to count how many td which have attribute "data-sortable-id".. and its not equal to any value on it..

Comment: I think the xpath is fine, its just that the page @ runtime does not have that element when you tried to access it. Maybe try printing it first and verify the page.

Comment: i've found the solution..find_element_by_css_selector("tr[data-sortable-id]")

Answer (score 3):

To find all the `<td>` tags which have attribute **data-sortable-id** you can use the following granular `xpath` :

```
"//table[@id='product']/tr//td[@data-sortable-id]"
```

Perhaps you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) in-conjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) clause as [visibility_of_all_elements_located](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located) as follows :

```
x = WebDriverWait(webdriver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='product']//tr//td[@data-sortable-id]")))
print(len(x))
```